# SELENIUM НАЖИМАЕТ на карточи организаций но на третьей выводит ошибку

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def cliknuli(obgekt):
    listt = obgekt.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='_zjunba']")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    for i in  listt :
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(i)).click()

latestchromedriver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path=latestchromedriver)


def main():
    driver.get('https://2gis.kz/almaty/search/Алматы%2C%20школа')

    time.sleep(2)

    kartochki = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='_awwm2v']")
    
    cliknuli(kartochki)


main()
```

выводит:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (176, 976). Other element would receive the click: ...

пытался использовать Wait для ожидания кликбэйтности но не помогло: все ровно что то перехватывает. Заранее  спасибо.